# Scala dispatch reboot timeout

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future, scala-dispatch

I am using the dispatch reboot library version 0.9.5 (http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) in my project. Via sbt I have the following line:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.9.5"
```

In the scala (2.9.2) repl (started using `sbt console` to get the appropriate dependency) and independent of my code I run the following session:

```
import dispatch._
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit._
val spoo = Http.threads(1).waiting( Duration(10, SECONDS ) )
```

(I believe that the third line sets up my own threadpool with one thread and a timeout of 10 seconds).

I then run this code repeatedly (in paste mode), to submit a future to fetch a particular url and then print the status code (asynchronously):

```
spoo(url("http://www.evapcool.com/products/commercial/")).either
    .map {
        case Right(r) => println( "S: " + r.getStatusCode())
        case Left(e)  => println( "E: " + e.toString ) }
```

Each time I run this line I wait for the status code to get printed before running the line again. For the first twenty to forty calls it works as expected. Then it reliably fails to report either a successful page reply or an exception. My assumption was that if this is caused by a timeout, I should expect the callback to fire after 10 seconds with the `Left` clause of the `Either` containing some form of timeout exception. But my experience is that this never comes.

Can anyone help tell me what I'm doing wrong?

#### Update

By the way, I am aware that there is a similar question (with answer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676359/scala-dispatch-library-how-to-handle-connection-failure-or-timeout) but I am looking for the official (i.e. intended by the library author) way to handle timeouts - and it appears to me that this is what the `waiting` method is designed for

Comment: What's the "reboot" part about?

Comment: @RandallSchulz I believe the reboot is a re-write to use async-http-client as the transport, and also to expose a bit more of an optional java-y api for those who are somewhat allergic to the number of symbolic methods in the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So an answer, although one I'm not enormously satisfied with - because it involves ignoring the rather nice looking `waiting` method on `Http` and playing directly with the async-http-client apis is this (inspired by the SO post linked in the question update):

```
val spoo = Http.threads( 1 ).configure
    { builder =>
        builder.setRequestTimeoutInMs( 10000 )
        builder.setConnectionTimeoutInMs( 10000 )

        builder
    }
```

My code now runs as expected. Ho hum...